# Adding a custom x-axis label to highstock graph

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to add an extra x-axis label to the end of a chart, like in the image below.

[image]

Is this possible?

I've checked out the API but don't see anything about adding or modifying single labels.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `formatter` function to customize the labels:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            if (this.isLast) {
                return 'Now'
            }

            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S.%L', this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5s3gbawr/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter